# improving shell algorithm

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a shell script.

I write a script:

```
for file in *.gif
do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    filename=${filename%.*}
    convert $file $filename.tlf
done
```

Is this right in your opinion? How can I add name changing?

PS: Please do not edit topic, because names of files are special information.

Comment: Notes: (1) The names are listed in a different order than will be generated by `*.gif`; the names will be generated in alphabetic order.  (2) The `basename` operation does nothing.  You could have written `filename=$(basename "$file" .gif)` to remove the suffix, or you can do what you do on the next line.  (3) You need a counter and an increment operation: `counter=1` outside the loop, `${counter}_$filename.tlf` as the second argument to `convert`, and `((counter++))` or similar to increment the counter.

Comment: Please don't deface your questions after people have taken the time to answer them. This isn't fair to people trying to answer you.

Answer (score 3):

```
nr=0
for file in *.gif; do
    nr=$(($nr+1))
    filename="$(basename "$file")"
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    convert "$file" "${nr}_$filename.tlf"
done
```

Comment: Don't forget the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use the [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/basename.html) command instead of parameter expansions, you should use it to its fullest power by giving it an extension suffix to drop. That will take care of both birds with one stone.

```
nr=0
for file in *.gif; do
  filename="$(( ++nr ))_$(basename "$file" .gif).tlf"
  convert "$file" "$filename"
done
```

You could also do the whole thing with parameter expansion:

```
nr=0
for file in *.gif; do
  filename="$(( ++nr ))_${file##*/}"
  filename="${filename%.*}"
  convert "$file" "$filename"
done
```

The benefit of the parameter expansions is that you don't invoke a subshell every iteration. Unless you need to process a lot of files, it won't make a difference.